# Xpath ,element wise conversion

Tags: r, shiny

From the following link, I need to express a xpath in terms of div, ul, li.
When I copy xpath with chrome, I get the following:

Example for one the xpath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[5]/span[2]
```

I tried to figure out the conversion solution, by looking at the details, once you see pressing on F12, but something went wrong.

Here is the link of the web site:
https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/istanbul-sisli-fulya-satilik/daire/7326-1354.

I need to express the xpath of "konut tipi","banyo sayısı" in the provided web link.

appreciate our support

Comment: @Vaibhav  the following code, only converts" konut tipi"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following expression to get the xpath by text values.

```
$x("//*[contains(text(),'Konut Tipi')]")
```

In you case it is bringing 2 values, so you need to know which one to choose from.

Comment: xidel --input-format html --output-format adhoc -e \
"//*[contains(text(),'Konut Tipi')]" \
$hemlak/10005103 2> /dev/null     it only converts>> konut tipi"

Comment: Did the above code worked for 'Konut Tipi'? If yes, you can just substitute 'Konut Tipi' with 'banyo sayıs'. e.g. "//*[contains(text(),'banyo sayıs')]". If not, please explain the exact issue you are facing.